# Using Nagios/Monit/Munin with Windows

Tags: monitoring, munin

I'm building a .NET 3.5 web app and I am thinking about all the fundamental issues as I work through the project, like monitoring, exception handling, the lot.

The app will obviously be small in size when it is rolled out because it won't have a high load until the site is heavily promoted (lines of code/cyclomatic complexity and so forth will be high, and the app will be commercial scale with the same considerations as large systems such as Facebook etc).

Anyway, I am going to outsource "foundation" services like monitoring to an open source solution to slash costs and dev time, so I can concentrate on business functionality and promotion. I want to use nagios with monit and munin as my tools for monitoring my system. The problem is, these tools are designed for the Linux/Unix stack. Does anyone here have experience of getting it to work with Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You will probably find it easier to run a second server running Linux than to shoe horn nagios and company into an environment that they were not developed for.

If you do insist on trying to run them in Windows, and if you have lots and lots of problems, *please* resist the urge to badmouth these products when you have not used them as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having an additional hardware server, you could use VMWare or VirtualBox for Windows, host a small Linux VM and install Nagios on it. It is pretty straight forward and the Nagios install is simple for DEB and RPM based distros (and others too presumably, but not sure).

//Nicholas

Answer (score 1):

Coming from an all windows environment we had to "bite-the-bullet" and install linux on VMWare to run Munin and maby Nagios later on. The only issues we had was learning Linux.